# Using Robot Framework for testing multiple user logins in the same file

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

My goal is to use Robot to take a list of login credentials and iterate through the list, logging into the page and essentially proving those users can see the page.

From what I've been finding, I need to use a Template, but I haven't found it very clear how do implement one when you have all the values you want to use in the same robot file.

I've been using https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst and http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Based on this example they have:

```
Templated test case
    [Template]    Example keyword
    first argument    second argument
```

They don't explicitly show an example of where the data is set up to run the test.

Here's what I have so far:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Test Access Levels of the new Page
Library  Selenium2Library
Test Template  Security Login Test

*** Test Cases ***

All Users Login Test
  Security Login Test  Login Test
  User1  Pass1
  User2  Pass2
  User3  Pass3    

*** Keywords ***
Enter User Name
    input text  working_username_field    need_to_put_username_here
Enter Password
    input text  working_password_field    need_corresponding_password_here
Click Login
    click element  working_login_button
Enter Store Number
    input text  working_store_field working_store_number
Click Search
    click element  working_search_button
Login Test
        open browser  working_url Chrome
        enter user name
        enter password
        click login
        enter store number
        click search
        go to   working_sub_url
```

What I don't know is how I then put those parameters into my Keywords so it will go through each on.

I know I could use a file for this, but that seems slightly more complicated, so I want to figure this way out first.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a suite-level template, each testcase is typically a single row. The first column is the test case name, and additional columns are arguments to the template keyword.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Security Login Test

*** Test Cases ***
# test case name  # username                 # password      
Normal user       joe.user@example.com       test123
Admin user        sally.admin@example.com    abc123
Banned user       boris.badguy@example.com   knockknock

*** Keywords ***
Security Login Test
    [Arguments]  ${username}  ${password}

     Enter username  ${username}
     Enter Password  ${password}

     The rest of your code here...

Enter username
    [Arguments]  ${username}
    log  entering username '${username}

Enter password
    [Arguments]  ${password}
    log  entering password '${password}'

The rest of your code here...
    log  another keyword
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's the `Security Login Test
    [Arguments]  ${username}  ${password}
` part that I didn't get.  I notice that in your test cases section you don't call out the template.  Is that because in the settings you're saying that the template is the keyword Security Login Test?

Comment: @ScottMacDonald: yes. Because the template is in the settings, you don't need to call the template directly in the tests.

Comment: I'm getting a message when I run saying that the Enter User Name is expecting 1 argument and getting 0.  Here's my current version: http://www.chopapp.com/#90u0l0ln

Comment: @ScottMacDonald: the error message is telling you the truth. The `enter user name` keyword _does_ take an argument, and you are _not_ providing one. Maybe you should provide one?

Comment: I had typed out a whole response before I realized what you meant.  Making progress!